# How can I solve Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, development-environment, adonis.js

If I run adonis migration:run, there exist error like this :

[image]

I using xampp

[image]

[image]

[image]

My env like this :

[image]

I using adonis js

It seems that the settings are correct, but why does the error still appear

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share your phpmyadmin `config-db.php`?

Comment: @CrBast `config-db.php` = `config.inc.php`? Right? See this link : https://pastebin.com/AD0xhftv

Comment: Can you also share your `config/database.js`?

Comment: @CrBast I had solve it. I uninstall xampp vm and install xampp. This problem occur because i use xampp vm